# Is there a way to tokenize my text data in a df column into phrases instead of words?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

Good day! I'm kinda new to Text Analytics and trying out something simple by myself. I have a df as following:

`data =  ['bank a earned 3 million usd through investing in certain funds and earned 500k eur from other investments in 2020', 'bank b earned 2 million usd from borrowing and 500k gbp from investments in 2020', 'bank c earned 600k chf and 300k aud from investing and borrowing respectively in 2020‘]`

`df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['text'])`
`

My goal is to try and find out what the different banks did to earn their money through text analytics. I have done some pre-processing such as removing punctuations and turning the data to all lowercase. I'm aware that I should also stem the words for better accuracy and remove stop words. However, one question popped up in my mind about tokenization. If I try to tokenize them, wouldn't the text lose its meaning from critically important phrases such as '2 million usd' or '300k aud'? If so, how do I tokenize it into phrases that retain the meaning of my text data?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can do it. This is an example with bigrams with your data, you can have trigrams if you replace 2 with 3. You can use other libraries too.

```
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
from nltk import word_tokenize 
from nltk.util import ngrams

df['tokenized_words']=df['text'].apply(word_tokenize)
df['tokenized_bigrams']=df['tokenized_words'].apply(lambda x: list(ngrams(x, 2)))
```

To give more context, its called n-gram tokenization and you can use bigrams (n=2), trigrams (n=3) and so on. Then, after splitting on n-grams you can find statistically the commonly used one and treat them as some feature maybe, if you only want to retain the commonly occurring ones. That is up to you to choose based on the problem you are trying to solve and how you want to approach it, and there are numerous possibilities. There is no strict answer in how you decide to tokenize. The reason why you are tokenizing is because you want to break down the stream of the text into smaller parts that can be more easily utilized further, for instance if you apply some machine learning algorithm. Moreover, you can use single tokens to analytically find those words that tend to be associated together to commonly occurring bigrams, without splitting in the beginning.

Comment: thank you for the answer, however when I tried the above snippet of code, it did not include the numbers, for instance, it looked like this `... ('earned', 'million'), ('million', 'usd'), ('usd', 'through') ...` and the 3 went missing. Is there anyway to make the tokenizer include numbers when tokenizing?

Comment: I tried it and its not removing the numbers for me, for instance list(ngrams(word_tokenize("bank a earned 3 million usd through investing in certain funds and earned 500k eur from other investments in 2020"),2)) is giving: [('bank', 'a'),
 ('a', 'earned'),
 ('earned', '3'),
 ('3', 'million'),....
I have version 3.7 of nltk.